# avoid creating duplicate variable names in function

Tags: r, function, global, assign

I have a `dataframe` and a `function` that creates a new variable, adds it to the dataframe and then `assign`s the dataframe back to the global environment. The problem is that if I rerun the function it creates a duplicate of the variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rms)
set.seed(10)
ds <- data.frame(
  ftime = rexp(200),
  fstatus = sample(0:1,200, replace = TRUE),
  x1 = runif(200),
  x2 = runif(200),
  x3 = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 200, replace = TRUE)))
ds
#model
s <- Surv(ds$ftime, ds$fstatus == 1) 
fit <- cph(s ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = ds, surv = TRUE, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

#function to add prediction to dataset
pred_fun <- function(time_to_sur, model) {
  
  pred_data <- ds[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")] %>% 
    mutate(ftime = time_to_sur,
           fstatus = 1) %>%   
    as.data.frame()
  
  ds$pred_var_tmp <-
    rms::survest(model, times = time_to_sur,
                 newdata = pred_data,
                 se.fit = FALSE, what = "survival")$surv
  
  #rename variable
  pred_var <- paste0("pred_prob_", as.character(time_to_sur), "_rms")
  names(ds)[names(ds) == "pred_var_tmp"] <- pred_var
  
  #assign dataset back to global environment
  assign("ds", ds, env = .GlobalEnv) 
}
```

The function works as it should:

```
pred_fun(time_to_sur = 0.2, fit)
names(ds)
# [1] "ftime"             "fstatus"           "x1"               
# [4] "x2"                "x3"                "pred_prob_0.2_rms"
```

But if I rerun it again, it creates a duplicate of the variable

```
pred_fun(time_to_sur = 0.2, fit)
names(ds)
# [1] "ftime"             "fstatus"           "x1"               
# [4] "x2"                "x3"                "pred_prob_0.2_rms"
# [7] "pred_prob_0.2_rms"
```

This is to be expected because the function create a new variable first with a different name and then assigns the name after. I thought the following might work in the function but it doesn't:

```
ds$eval(substitute(paste0("pred_prob_", as.character(tt), "_rms"))) <-
    rms::survest(model, times = time_to_sur,
                 newdata = pred_data,
                 se.fit = FALSE, what = "survival")$surv
```

How can I fix this and what is best practices in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: What is desired output?  Do you want to replace the pred_prob_0.2_rms or add a new column with a different name?

Comment: And, not relevant to the question but (I think) useful.  Add `ds` as the first argument to the function and `return(ds)` as the final line of the function.  That will remove the need for the ugly (and dangerous and limiting) global `assign`in the current final line.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I want to overwrite the old variable so there is only one `pred_prob_0.2_rms` in the dataset

Comment: @Limey do you mean `ds <- pred_fun(ds, time_to_sur = 0.2, fit)`? I was trying to avoid having to assign it after but maybe that is safer

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  It's not only safer, but makes the function more generic.  And therefore more usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G. Grothendieck and @Limey, the following simplification works (`pred_fun_final`) although I do get a `warning` message.

```
#original function in OP
pred_fun_original <- function(time_to_sur, model) {
  
  pred_data <- ds[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")] %>% 
    mutate(ftime = time_to_sur,
           fstatus = 1) %>%   
    as.data.frame()
  
  ds$pred_var_tmp <-
    rms::survest(model, times = time_to_sur,
                 newdata = pred_data,
                 se.fit = FALSE, what = "survival")$surv
  
  #rename variable
  pred_var <- paste0("pred_prob_", as.character(time_to_sur), "_rms")
  names(ds)[names(ds) == "pred_var_tmp"] <- pred_var

  assign("ds", ds, env = .GlobalEnv) 
}
pred_fun_original(time_to_sur = 0.2, fit)

#save created variable
test1 <- ds$pred_prob_0.2_rms

#remove pred_prob_0.2_rms
ds <- ds %>% 
  select(-pred_prob_0.2_rms)
```

New function with `warning`:

```
#fixed function
pred_fun_final <- function(data, time_to_sur, model) {
  
  newName <- paste0("pred_prob_", as.character(time_to_sur), "_rms")
  pred_data <- data[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")] %>% 
    mutate(ftime = time_to_sur,
           fstatus = 1) %>%   
    as.data.frame()
  
  data <- data %>% 
    mutate({{newName}} := rms::survest(model, times = time_to_sur,
                                       newdata = pred_data,
                                       se.fit = FALSE, what = "survival")$surv)
  
  data
}
ds <- pred_fun_final(ds, time_to_sur = 0.2, fit)
# Warning message:
# Problem with `mutate()` column `pred_prob_0.2_rms`.
# i `pred_prob_0.2_rms = ...$NULL`.

#save variable
test2 <- ds$pred_prob_0.2_rms
```

The two variables are not identical but that is because one is named and the other is not (`as.numeric()` would fix this). It doesn't explain the `warning` message though.

```
identical(test1, test2)
#FALSE
str(test1)
#  num [1:200] 0.906 0.9 0.884 0.884 0.886 ...
str(test2)
#  Named num [1:200] 0.906 0.9 0.884 0.884 0.886 ...
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:200] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) Base R** This will overwrite the existing column if it already exists.  This overwrites Time, which is originally c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7) with 11:16.

```
newName <- "Time" # duplicated column name
values <- 11:16
replace(BOD, newName, values)
##   Time demand
## 1   11    8.3
## 2   12   10.3
## ...
```

If the new column name did not exist then it creates a new column.

```
newName <- "Time2" # new column name, not duplicate
values <- 11:16
replace(BOD, newName, values)
##   Time demand Time2
## 1    1    8.3    11
## 2    2   10.3    12
## ...
```

**2) dplyr** If you would like to use dplyr for this then:

```
library(dplyr)

newName <- "Time" # duplicated column name
values <- 11:16
mutate(BOD, {{newName}} := values)
##   Time demand
## 1   11    8.3
## 2   12   10.3
## ...

newName <- "Time2" # new column name, not duplicate
values <- 11:16
mutate(BOD, {{newName}} := values)
##   Time demand Time2
## 1    1    8.3    11
## 2    2   10.3    12
## ...
```

### Other

*Functional nature of R*. R is a functional language and normally functions are written to pass the input in via the arguments and to pass the output as the return value.  Here x is the input and y is the output.

```
# ok
f <- function(x) x + 1
y <- f(3)
y
## [1] 4
```

It is better *not* to do this:

```
#  not good
f <- function() assign("y",  x + 1, .GlobalEnv)
x <- 3
f()
y
## [1] 4
```

*Replacement functions*. Although not frequently used R does support replacement functions and syntax like this (see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment).  For example, `names<-` is a commonly used replacement function. We create a duplicate of BOD first so that we don't overwrite it.  This preserves the input making it easier to debug.

```
`f<-` <- function(x, value) replace(x, "Time", value)
BOD2 <- BOD
f(BOD2) <- 11:16
BOD2
##   Time demand
## 1   11    8.3
## 2   12   10.3
## ...
```

Comment: thanks for the useful insights. I thought the OP was adequate with a minimal reproducible example. As it was within a function I also thought it was more complicated than a simple overwriting problem. I have added a solution based on what you have added here. There is a warning and I am not sure if you know do I need to worry about this?